# Save Workbook with Macros on specific path

Tags: excel, save, excel-2007, vba

i have create a excel workbook for a project. this workbook contains a lot of macros and should be like a template.

After the user open the "template"-Workbook, a macro is calling. this macro should save this current file to a specific path and with a new name(current date and if the same file exists with the current time) on the machine.

After the "save" macro is done, the user work on the new workbook

I use (maybe) the common way to save this workbook (EDIT:complete **working** Save-Sub)

```
  ' Save the File into a new Directory

  '
  ' Set a new File name , to prevent overwriting the template
  ' Filenname: date of today
  ' if the same file exists, set the current time to the current date
  ' Filenname : date-of-today + Time-of-Now


  Dim DateOfToday, TimeOfToday As String
  Dim fileName, fileNameWithTime As String
  Dim FilePathComplete, FilePathCompletesTime As String


 'get the current Day and Time
  DateOfToday = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy")
  TimeOfToday = Format(Now, "hh.mm")

  'Get the Documents Directory Path
  FilePath = FileInfo.GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_PERSONAL) + "\Workbooks\" 

 ' name of the directory
  fileName = "Workbooks-"+DateOfToday+".xlsm"

 ' filename if the file already exists
  filenameWithTime = "Workbooks-"+DateOfToday+"-"+TimeOfToday+".xlsm"

 FilePathComplete = specialFolderPath + fileName
 FilePathCompletesTime = specialFolderPath + fileNameWithTime 

 On Error GoTo DispFehler
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 If Dir(FilePathComplete) <> "" Then

 ChDir specialFolderPath
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePathCompletesTime,     FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Else
ChDir specialFolderPath
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePathComplete,     FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False


End If

DispFehler:
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Remove the  `On Error GoTo DispFehler` and check what kind of error it gives you. What is not working?

Comment: (a) Edit your question to also show the part of the code declaring and setting the values of `FilePaths`, `FilePathComplete` and `FilePathCompletesTime`.  Without seeing that code, the most likely answer is "Your `FilePaths`, `FilePathComplete` and `FilePathCompletesTime` are not set correctly."  (b) Move your error handler out of the inside of the `False` leg of the `If` statement (it might work, even when an error occurs in the `True` leg, but it is definitely **not** a good idea to do it that way) and ensure you `Resume` from the error handler after you have processed the error.

Comment: Thanks for your hints! I renew my sub and now it works for me ! (I edit my Question again)